# Rails model name lookup: strange uninitialized constant error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller that should output suggestions for a form. The controller is under the Admin::Shop namespace and is located at app/controllers/admin/shop/suggest_controller.rb

```
class Admin::Shop::SuggestController < Admin::AdminsAreaController
  def index
    render:json => Shop::Product.all.group(:name).pluck(:name) and return
  end
end
```

Shop::Product is a model defined under app/models/shop/product.rb as follows:

```
class Shop::Product < PostgresRecord
  # ...
end
```

I can run queries on this model from the console and rspec tests without any issues. But when I try querying from within the controller, if the file changes (I edit something and save) I get `uninitialized constant Admin::Shop::SuggestController::Shop`.

To get it to work again I have to restart the server (using Puma).

I get the same behavior when trying to query from other controllers in other namespaces.

There's nothing relevant in the logs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `::Shop::Product.all.group`. That'll cause ther constant lookup to begin in the global namespace.

Comment: You're awesome, it works. But why would it not work like that "by default" ?

Comment: Probably related to top-level constant lookup, which was changed in [ruby 2.5](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/12/25/ruby-2-5-0-released/). Which version are you on? My guess is it found a match for `Shop` at `Admin::Shop`, and didn't know how to backtrack when if then failed to find `Admin::Shop::Product`, so it just bailed and complained that it didn't find the constant you were looking for.

Comment: I'm on 2.5.5 so I guess that's it. Is there a way to set up constant lookups to start at the top for this particular namespace? So I can avoid having to prefix everything with :: as I have like 20 models here.

Comment: It has to do with how rails does constant loading and look up. There are a number of good articles on the interwhozits.

Comment: Thank you so much once again, I lost so many neurons trying to figure this out. Maybe you can post an answer when you have a moment, just in case someone else will run into this issue later.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz - Out of curiosity, what makes you think this is a ruby, and not rails, issue?

Comment: Oh it could be Rails. I just suspected it had to do with top level constant lookup since the proposed workaround specified the top level explicitly. Probably one good test would be to see if it behaves differently with eager loading config'd to true.

Comment: @AndrewSchwartz - Also out of curiosity, with eager loading configured to true, how would you expect the behavior to change and what would this test tell you? BTW, I almost always have eager loading set to true in my development environment.

Comment: I’d also be interested to know why/how it always worked in my controller specs but not in the actual web server after changing the code which forces a reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `::Shop::Product.all.group`. That'll cause the constant lookup to begin in the global namespace.

There are a number of good [articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=constant+lookup+rails) written on the subject. Give them a read!